# How does pointer increment compare with index increment in C

Tags: c, pointers, integer, increment

consider the following two code:

```
void PrintLetter(char *src)
{
 while(*src != '\0')
 {
   printf("%c",*src);
   src++;
 }
}
```

and

```
void PrintLetter(char *src)
{
 int i;
 for(i=0;src[i];i++)
  printf("%c",src[i]);
}
```

Is there any performance difference between the two?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I don't see how this is a *bad* question. Maybe OP doesn't know about optimizers but that's not a reason to downvote, is it?

Comment: Yeah seriously. I gave a perfectly legit answer, and got 3 downvotes. Pointer arithmetic as done in the first block is slightly faster without relying on compiler optimizations. Period. And yet I got 3 downvotes? Are people just spiteful or ignorant this morning?

Comment: @Chris - Who is interested in performance without compiler optimizations?!

Comment: @Bo: the bigger question is, who assumes with 100% certainty that the compiler will always do the right thing?

Comment: Well, you could run some tests to see what will be the results - with and without compiler optimizations.

Comment: @Chris - So you are saying that pointer increment works but indexing is not?! What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Bo: this isn't a question about what "works", this is a question about which is faster. They both work, but you're assuming that the compiler will ALWAYS optimize the second into the first, which IMHO is not always the best position.

Comment: @Chris - It works with the compilers I'm using. I assume it will continue to do so.

Comment: @Bo: what an insightful and holistic answer. *Slow clap*

Comment: @Chris - So you have specific evidence of where it doesn't work or are just pessimizing for no reason?

Comment: @Bo: yes, I have many instances where pointer arithmetic is just plain faster period. I do a lot of work with image I/O and doing offset calculations makes the program painfully slow even with optimizations (this is mainly because there are two dimensions and the compiler simply isn't intelligent enough to optimize a 2-step offset calculation). So instead of `img[i+j*width]` I would write `*img; img++`. The compiler does not always know best. A programmer needs to be more intelligent than his/her tools.

Comment: @Bo: also, apologies if I flew off the handle. Nothing is more prone to send me into a rant than "it works for me".

Comment: @Chris - It's ok. I have just done this for a very long time and learned that you should trust your compiler. :-) The new guys should not attempt micro optimizations, but work on the algorithms.

Comment: Oh I'm not advocating always optimizing. I know the first rule of optimizing (don't do it). I'm just saying that there are circumstances when you have to realize that it's just a dumb tool, and you need to know its limitations. And when it comes to something like image I/O, even though I'd love to avoid optimizing (i.e. making it impossible to read), it's pretty much the only way to get reasonable performance. The compiler, though *usually* right, isn't always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None whatsoever. The compiler will perform its optimizations regardless of the form you are writing. The underlying assembly code is the same.

Comment: +1 Checked, LLVM gives **exactly** the same assembly code for both (`diff` returns no results) :)

Comment: Also, an extremely good optimizer would optimize it to `printf("%s", src);`.

Answer (score 2):

Any performance difference will depend on the compiler.

Some small embedded systems have quite simplistic compilers that may produce slightly different code for one than the other -- though without testing, it's hard to guess which might end up "better" (though if I had to guess "blindly", I'd probably pick the first).

With the compilers on typical desktop/server systems (e.g., gcc, VC++, EDG) you're likely to get (essentially) identical results either way, so choosing between them is purely a matter of picking what you find more readable.